# Compile specific source list and generate dependency

Tags: c, makefile

I have below file list:

```
fd1/foo.c
fd2/foo.c
fd2/bar.c
fd2/bar.h
```

I want to compile fd1/foo.c and fd2/bar.c. fd2/foo.c is an excluded one. If I use vapth to select all source files, the fd2/foo.c will be compiled. So I want to specify the source list:

```
SRC_C = fd1/foo.c fd2/bar.c
```

Since I can't use vpath, so I can only compile SRC_C something like this:

```
SRC_O = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C))
SRC_C_LIST = $(notdir $(SRC_C))
OBJ_LIST = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C_LIST) )
.PHONY: all
all: $(OBJ_LIST)
    ar rvs foobar.a $(OBJ_LIST)
$(SRC_O): %.o : %.c
    gcc -c  $< -I inc/ -MM -MF $(patsubst .o,.d,$(notdir $@)) -o $(notdir $@)
```

But I also want add dependency rules. But the dependency file seems only contain object target without original folder names:

```
foo.o : src/foo.c inc/bar.h
```

How do I to use dependency file in this case? Thanks.

### Solutions

Per suggestion from Joachim, I modify my solution as below. Seems work:

```
SRC_C = fd1/foo.c fd2/bar.c
SRC_O = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C))
SRC_C_LIST = $(notdir $(SRC_C))
OBJ_LIST = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SRC_C_LIST) )
SRC_D_LIST = $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$(OBJ_LIST))
.PHONY:all
all: $(SRC_O)
    ar rvs foobar.a $(OBJ_LIST)
$(SRC_O): %.o : %.c
    arm-none-eabi-gcc -c $< -I inc/ -o $@ -MM -MT $@ -MF $(notdir $(patsubst %.o,%.d,$@))
-include $(SRC_D_LIST)
```

Comment: How do you generate the dependencies? Could it have something to do with all those `notdir` function calls, which removes the directory name and leave only the file name?

Comment: @Joachim, I've modified my post and add dependency options.

Comment: `vpath` is just how make finds listed prerequisites. If you don't list a prerequisite then make won't find it and if you don't try to build a target that depends on it then make won't even look for it. So you absolutely can use vpath even with specific targets/prerequisites. You have to filter out the one you don't want though if you are using `wildcard`/etc.

Comment: If you show the original `vpath`-including makefile that didn't do what you wanted we could probably help fix that one instead of this [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/276279). (Though this is, in its own right, a valid question too.)

Answer (score 1):

Using implicit rules, if you do not mind having the `.o` and `.d` files along the corresponding `.c` files:

```
LIB := foobar.a
SRC := fd1/foo.c fd2/bar.c
OBJ := $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP := $(OBJ:.o=.d)

CC       := arm-none-eabi-gcc
ARFLAGS  := rvs
CPPFLAGS := -MMD -MP -I inc

.PHONY: all
.PRECIOUS: $(OBJ)

all: $(LIB)

$(LIB): $(LIB)($(OBJ))

-include $(DEP)
```